# Confirmation Model with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars

I have a link aimed to `'/FridgeTemperatureRoute'` and a checkbox. Purpose of the checkbox is to show the user whether the check has been done or not.

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a id="FridgeTemperatureBtn" href="/FridgeTemperatureRoute">Fridge and Freezer Temperature</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input id="FridgeTemperatureCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="" value="" disabled {{fridgeFreezerTemperatureReturnObj}}>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Summary of code**

You'll see this line `{{fridgeFreezerTemperatureReturnObj}}` - this is from Node JS server, which determines whether the `checkbox` `is ticked or not`.

**Jquery, Javascript and Bootstrap Model**

Next, I am aiming to open a bootstrap `model` on user click, but only if the `checkbox` is `ticked`. If the user clicks and the checkbox is checked, then open a bootstrap model asking whether to continue to the `href` or simply cancel rendering the next page.

```
  <!-- Modal confirm -->
<div class="modal" id="confirmModal" style="display: none; z-index: 1050;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body" id="confirmMessage">
        <p>You have already completed this check, do you want to do it again?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmCancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById('FridgeTemperatureCheckBox').checked){
      $('#FridgeTemperatureBtn').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
      $('#FridgeTemperatureBtn').attr('data-target', '#confirmModal');
      document.getElementById('FridgeTemperatureBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        $('#confirmOk').click(function(){
          window.location.href = '/FridgeTemperatureRoute';
        });        
      });
    }
</script>
```

**Summary**

I have it working - but I believe it can be simplified. Just looking for some reviews and where I can improve on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Be consistent

If you're going to use jQuery, it would be stylistically appropriate (and terser) to use it instead of the native DOM methods. For example:

```
if(document.getElementById('FridgeTemperatureCheckBox').checked){
```

can turn into

```
if ($('#FridgeTemperatureCheckBox').is(':checked')) {
```

To translate `getElementById` to jQuery or `querySelector`, put a `#` in front of the ID you want to select.

Or you can use vanilla DOM methods everywhere if you prefer (like I do) - but whatever you choose to do, it would be good to do it *consistently*, otherwise you'll probably confuse future readers of the code.

**HTML too**: On a similar note about consistency - with your element IDs, better to choose either `camelCase`, `PascalCase`, or `kebab-case` everywhere, but don't mix and match different styles, else you're more likely to run into typo problems when you don't have a set style and mis-remember which style you used. (You can also consider using classes instead of IDs, since IDs with their [automatically global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278) are unintuitive and can cause bugs.)

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code

Rather than selecting the same element multiple times, eg:

```
$('#FridgeTemperatureBtn').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
$('#FridgeTemperatureBtn').attr('data-target', '#confirmModal');
```

It would be more elegant to select the element *once* and save it in a variable. Or, even better, since `.attr` returns the existing jQuery collection, just chain the `.attr` calls:

```
$('#FridgeTemperatureBtn')
  .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
  .attr('data-target', '#confirmModal');
```

**Attach listener once, immediately**: It looks like the `confirmModal` only becomes visible when the user clicks the button *and* has already completed the check, is that correct? If so, consider attaching the `#confirmOk` click listener immediately, rather than only after the `#FridgeTemperatureBtn` is clicked. (Attaching identical listeners multiple times won't cause problems in this case, but it's peculiar logic.)

**Semantics:** Your `FridgeTemperatureBtn` is an `<a>`, not a button, so its ID's name should probably be tweaked. If you have it styled to look like a button with your CSS, it would probably be a bit [more semantically appropriate](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/hwourm/friendly_reminder_that_visually_styling_a_button/) to surround a `<button>` inside an `<a>` instead.

**Unchangeable checkbox UX**: The `#FridgeTemperatureCheckBox` is `disabled`. Having it be a checkbox is a bit unintuitive, because users generally expect checkboxes to be clickable. Consider informing the user that the check has already been done some other way, such as by adding a [checkmark](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/green-check-mark-icon-tick-symbol-522874111) (not a checkbox), or by changing the background color, or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. Sectioning is a lot more suited for CR which is often about nitpicking a bunch of things.